# Multilevel static nested class producing wrong output

Tags: java, inner-classes

When following code is run it prints `"X.Q"` instead of `"A<T>.X.Q"` as required by the language specification.

```
    class A<T> {
    static class X {
        static class Q {
            public static void main() {
                System.out.println("A<T>.X.Q");
            }
        }
    }
}

class B extends A<B.Y.Q> {
    static class Y extends X {
    } // X here is inherited from A
}

class X {
    static class Q {
        public static void main() {
            System.out.println("X.Q");
        }
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B.Y.Q.main();
    }
}
```

Can some one help me understand what will be the output of this program, as per my understanding it should be `"A<T>.X.Q"`  instead of  `"X.Q"` , Please correct me if i am mistaken some where

Comment: Are you not able to see the code snippet whose main class name is Test

Comment: Sorry, I read too fast.

Comment: It's ok ..please check the code and share your thoughts... :)

Comment: It should print "A<T>.X.Q"

Comment: But since the X that Y extends is the one with "X.Q", why should it not print that?

Comment: @pulp_fiction There are two `X`s there, one from the outside scope, and one from inside `A<T>`. When compiler resolves the name, `X` from the outside scope "wins".

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, you could post the relevant part of the JLS as an answer. Show Stopper seems to think it's the other way around. I have no idea and am curious.

Comment: `// X here is inherited from A` is false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason that you are getting `"X.Q"` printed is that `X` refers to the class `X` scoped to the unnamed package, not `A<T>.X`. It does not matter that "outside" `X` is declared *after* `B`, because Java compiler sees it before resolving the name of `B.Y`'s base class.

You can force inheritance from `A.X` in your code as follows:

```
class B extends A<B.Y.Q> {
    static class Y extends A.X {
    } //                   ^^
      //                Add this
}
```

[Demo 1.](http://ideone.com/Xu3qbP)

**Edit: (thanks [user695022](https://stackoverflow.com/users/695022/user695022) for the comment)**

Curiously, the problem goes away if the outer class is not generic:

```
class A {
    static class X {
        static class Q {
            public static void main() {
                System.out.println("A<T>.X.Q");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo 2.](https://ideone.com/JUoUaU)

Comment: That's not true. Without generics Y extends A.X even if you just write X. Here, I forked your demo: https://ideone.com/JUoUaU

Comment: @user695022 Thanks for the demo, I edited the answer to include it.

Comment: @user695022 : That's very interesting because inheritance then DO play a part in resolution. This is not intuitive at all then. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, lets see what you have here. As per my understanding, your argument is basically about `Y extends X` but which `X`. The access by defaults to the outer scope. If you delete the outer `X`, it won't compile because `X` is not available. For inner static classes, you will have to either put explicit import statement or reference it with fully qualified name while extending.

It is the default convention in resolution. This also makes sense **if you realize that there can only be 1 class with the same name within the outer scope but you can have many inner static classes with the same name.** You need a convention for access for all of these. This convention solves it in a *seemingly* intuitive manner(otherwise, you would have to type fully qualified name for all the `X`'s while extending)

If you consider the outer one, it should print, `"X.Q"` which it does.

Answer (score 1):

Method main of Q, that prints X.Q is the called method because B.Y extends X (not A.X) whose Q method is hiding A.X.Q.main method.

It is a little confused to follow up, simply adding traces or debugging step by step you can see the full call tree.